# $location.path doesn't change in a factory with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-factory

My factory looks like:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('httpInterceptor',['$q','$location', '$rootScope', function($q, $location, $rootScope){
    return {
      response: function(response) {

        if(response.success === false) {
console.log("Redirecting");
            $location.path('/login');
            return $q.reject(response);
        }

        return response || $q.when(response);
      }
    }
}]);
```

It spits out the log, but doesn't change the path. What can I do to make this happen?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579938/location-path-not-working-from-http-interceptor/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation for $location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) says:

> Note that the setters don't update window.location immediately. Instead, the $location service is aware of the scope life-cycle and coalesces multiple $location mutations into one "commit" to the window.location object during the scope $digest phase.

Hence, if the rejection of the promise has an effect on `$location`, then you may not see the intended change.

To force a change outside of the angular life-cycle, you can set the `hash` using `window.location` and then force a reload of the page. This will, of course, stop execution of any code which follows and erase the session, but that might be what you want if the user is not logged in.

Comment: I found it very frustrating to not be able to get various angular solutions to redirection working, and having to resort to window.location for my redirection.

Answer (score 6):

There are certain cases where $location will not redirect if it is outside angular's apply cycle. Try wrapping the $location inside the $apply.

```
$rootScope.$apply( function(){$location.path('/somelocatin'); } );
```

Comment: are you cheating Angular?

Comment: is there a risk using this method? I used it - and it worked. can this affect the application state?

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me on Angular 1.3.14

```
myServices.factory('Factory', ['$rootScope', '$location', function ($rootScope, $location) {
  // do something and redirect
  $location.path('path')
  $rootScope.$apply()
}])
```

Notice that the `$rootScope.$apply()` is after the `$location.path('path')` call, for some reason wrapping it inside the $apply call callback as suggested above wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$location.path('#/login');
```

instead of

```
$location.path('/login');
```