# AngularJS $location.path doesn't work on Parse Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

My parse/AngularJS application is using Promises. 
The **login** function was suppose to redirect the user with **$location.path**, BUT I had to tweak it to make it work according to this post:

[$location.path doesn't change in a factory with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499323/location-path-doesnt-change-in-a-factory-with-angularjs)

According to this SO user, you need to replace the call to **$location.path** with

```
$rootScope.$apply( function(){$location.path('/somelocatin'); } );
```

See answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19738154/1743693

This solved the issue, but I have to understand: **WHY doesn't the native call work? and HOW does the tweak solve the issue?** how do I know I'm not screwing up the AngularJS cycle? or is it something that is related more to Parse implementation of the Promise pattern?

This is the login code:

```
    function login() {
        vm.dataLoading = true;
        var response = AuthenticationService.Login(vm.email, vm.password).then(
            function (user) {
                vm.dataLoading = false;
                //$location.path('/'); -- <-- **doesn't work**
                vm.user = Parse.User.current().getEmail();
                $rootScope.$apply(function () { $location.path('/'); });
            },
            function () {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () { $location.path('/login'); });
                FlashService.Error(response.message);
                vm.dataLoading = false;
            });
    };
```

And the Authentication service implementation:

```
    function Login(username, password, success, error) {

        return Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
            success: function (user) {
                return user;
            },
            error: function (user, error) {
                return { user: user, error: error };
            }
        });

    }
```

(Original Login source can be found here: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/03/10/AngularJS-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `$location` [is tightly tied](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/src/ng/location.js#L945) to Angular digest cycles, as well as many other Angular built-in services, all that `$location.path` [does is updating internal $$path property](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.5/src/ng/location.js#L487). It will be used to update the path during the next digest.

And because `$http` is tied to digests as well, it triggers the digest when the promise is being resolved or rejected. Generally there's no need to worry to trigger the digest manually, $location will update the location during the next digest. The other answer in the cited question [states this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19738044/3731501) unambiguously.

Since the promise wasn't provided by built-in service but by `Parse`, the digest needs to be triggered manually, this way Angular 'knows' that the location was updated. Consider

```
$location.path('/');
$rootScope.$apply();
```

syntax instead if it pleases you more.

It is possible to set up a watcher to investigate when the digest hits and what happens with location path at that moment

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
  console.log('digest! and the path is ' + $location.$$path);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was breaking my head but `$scope.$apply();` did the job for me perfectly. Didn't know that this method also applies to forceful updating  of `$location`.

Comment: This is not really about `$location`, this is about making Angular aware of the changes that were made in non-Angular async callbacks (and Parse `then` callback is the one). Unless you really want to examine Angular internals each time this happens, it is reasonable to assume that Angular services always rely on digest cycle somehow, and `$rootScope.$apply()` should be called at the end of non-Angular callback.