# Parse.com + AngularJS ngRoute - route on log in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I want my SPA to redirect the user to */home* after logging in. The first click on `Log In` logs in the user. The second click - redirects. But everything should happen on the first click.

If I get rid of the *User.logIn()* code and promise, the redirection works the first time. Why is that?

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.message = 'Login page!';        
    $scope.update = function(usr) {
        User.logIn(usr.name, usr.password)
        .then(function() {
            $location.path('/home');
        }, function(err) {
            alert(err.message);
        })}
}]);
```

Button code:

```
<button ng-click="update(usr)">Log In</button>
```

I tried putting the *$location* code in another *then*-operation(just in case) but it didn't work.

**EDIT:**
I kinda got it working. Not exactly what you suggested but you gave me an idea. Still, I'm reading about events in AngularJS at the moment. And see if I could eventually come up with something closer to your idea - with the promise.

```
$scope.goHome = function() {
    $location.path('/home');
};
```

And the button:

```
<button ng-click="goHome()" ng-mousedown="update(usr)">Log In</button>
```

**EDIT 2:** 
In case someone is having the same problem, I just found 2 questions on the matter. The first explains why rerouting doesn't work in a Parse promise and how to make it work, the second also has useful info:

[AngularJS $location.path doesn't work on Parse Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592847/angularjs-location-path-doesnt-work-on-parse-promise)

[$location.path doesn't change in a factory with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499323/location-path-doesnt-change-in-a-factory-with-angularjs)

Comment: Try replacing route('home') thats in the promise with "logon"  event .  From the promise , you can have the event bubble to appropriate listener which the calls the "route api" for /home

Comment: @RobertRowntree I edited my question.

Comment: So, your idea was to put a separate method in the success promise which routes the user to _/home_, right? If so, it didn't work. Or if I misunderstood, would you care to provide some code/example?

Comment: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.thg3mkbru   see "login-sucess" event  fired within a promise.then ...

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thanks!