# angularjs navigate to route from factory/service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Why $location.url( "/messages" ); is not working? is there any restriction about $location inside a factory in AngularJS? any idea what is going on?

If I'm doing something wrong can you please tell my how should I redirect to another url "/messages"? I can't reload the page using so $window is not an option.

Thanks

My factory:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.conversation')
        .factory('conversationFactory', conversation);

    conversation.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$q', 'authFactory', '$location'];

    function conversation($rootScope, $q, authFactory, $location) {

        var service = {
            changeLocation: changeLocation
        };

        return service;

        function changeLocation() {
            $location.url( "/messages" ); // recarga MIERDA!!!!!
        }

    }

})();
```

Route works fine:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
            .module('app.messages')
            .config(configFunction);

    configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function configFunction($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/messages', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/messages/messages.html',
                    controller: 'messagesController',
                    controllerAs: 'meC',
                    resolve: {
                        user: function ($q, $timeout, authFactory) {
                            return authFactory.isLoggedInPromise();
                        }
                    }
                }).when('/compose/:to?', {
                    templateUrl: 'app/messages/compose.html',
                    controller: 'composeController',
                    controllerAs: 'mcC',
                    resolve: {
                        user: function ($q, $timeout, authFactory) {
                            return authFactory.isLoggedInPromise();
                        }
                }
        });
    }

})();
```

Comment: Unless I'm confused, you're not using `angular-ui-router` (a 3rd party library) at all, but rather the built in angular router. I almost posted a ui-router specific answer (`$state.go(...)`) before realizing this...

Comment: I went ahead and editted that for ya' ;-)

Comment: Check out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499323/location-path-doesnt-change-in-a-factory-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

use `$location.path( "/messages" );`

Answer (score 1):

I did:

$location.path( "/messages" ); // and then
$rootScope.$apply()

[$location.path doesn't change in a factory with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499323/location-path-doesnt-change-in-a-factory-with-angularjs)